# Playback device problems

Tags: playback, pro-tools, hardware, mbox-2, software

I keep getting this message when I try to start Protools...

"Protools could not initialize current playback device. Please make sure the device has been configured correctly".
I can't understand why it now has trouble identifying my my mbox 2. Logic can see it, reason as well.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Made a quick adjustment to your tags so it's easier to be appropriately logged and searched - 'Sound Devices' on here refers to the Sound Devices line of products.  Hopefully someone can help!  my only thought is the my 003 kicks back a similar type error when I forget to switch it out of ASIO mode for regular computer playback (at least Soundminer does).   Maybe it has something to do with this?

Comment: some more information would help us generate some suggestions. OS version, Pro Tools version, any recent updates to computer/software, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have you done any recent updates?  Also, what OS and version of Pro Tools are you running?  I've encountered this problem in a variety of ways.  Sometimes I've even gotten this error after a flash drive pulled out without ejecting.  When this happens in OSX 10.6.x, it causes permissions errors that severely affect Pro Tools 8. Disk Repair usually will do the trick for that.  Also, the MBox2's require newer drivers, so if you haven't updated the drivers, you might also try that. The first thing I usually will try is a computer restart.  I'm assuming you probably tried that (and probably some other stuff as well).  Also, if you get totally stuck go to the DUC (avid.duc.com).  Search your error and chances are, you'll find an answer--most likely from Avid.

Hope that helps a little.